# How does one use Conway's Game of Life as a basis for a public cryptosystem?

Tags: security

I've read this article about it and it mentions how you can use Conway's game of life to encrypt a say a plain text document. I still don't quite get how this works. Would someone be willing to give a clear example to how this works? Thanks.

(article in question)

http://web.stanford.edu/~cdebs/GameOfLife/

Comment: Given how wrong the article is about how signing messages works in RSA, and given how absurdly insecure the proposed signature algorithm would be, I have no confidence in the strength of the encryption algorithm listed.

Comment: That said, if you want us to explain the algorithm, you'll have to be a lot more specific about what actually confuses you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. There is no currently known way to do that, and it is unlikely that one exists.

The section of the web page you're referring to is discussing cellular automata *in general*, not specifically Conway's Game of Life automaton. In fact, the system described in [the original article the web page references](http://www.complex-systems.com/pdf/01-1-4.pdf) uses an *inhomogenous* cellular automaton (that is, one where the rules are different for each cell), not a homogenous one like Game of Life (where the rules are uniform).